# Custom Send Email Button from Opportunity with "To" (address) related to custom object

Tags: custom-button

So I'm currently trying to populate the "TO" address which should be a custom object's(Partner) Email

Here's what I tried -

```
https://na3.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Opportunity.PartnerId__c}&rtype=a0U/o&p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
```

rtype - a0U/o (Partner object home page)

Error I receive -

> **Unable to Access Page**
>    The value of the "p2_lkid" parameter contains a
>   character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed
>   length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the
>   value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to
>   our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were
>   requesting as well as any other related information.

What am I doing wrong ? Here's a snapshot of where I want to populate the email field from Partner
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not misspelling `Opportunity.PartnerId__c`? Maybe it should be `Opportunity.Partner__c.Id`.

Comment: I used the merge field generated from the custom button. So it should be correct. But I'm not sure if populating Partner Id will fetch me the Partner's Email field.

Answer (score 1):

So I've done some tests on my end and this is what I found out:

1. If you manually click on lookup icon next to the `To` field you'll see that Salesforce lists only Contacts. This means that `p2_lkid` can only contain ID of a `Contact` record, and if that ID is of any other object type you'll get the exact same error you are getting. So check that `Opportunity.PartnerId__c` returns an ID to the actual record.
2. Next, when you get the **Unable to Access Page** error, if you are inside Chrome press `F12` and look at `Console` outputs. There should be a `500 (Server Error)` with a link that your custom button tried to open - you can use this to debug if the ID and other parameters were correctly populated.

[image: 500 (Server Error)]

3. I believe that you'll have to use the `{!URLENCODE}` function for the `rtype` part of your string as the `/` character in `a0U/o` will break the URL and you'll get the same **Unable to Access Page** error for your `rtype`. So, format the `rtype` parameter like following - `..&rtype={!URLENCODE("a0U/o")}&..`
4. Finally, if I were you I'd start debugging the issue by using only `p2_lkid` parameter and omit the other two. So create a custom button with following URL (`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Opportunity.PartnerId__c}`) and see if `To` field is populated correctly. If you make that work than you can move on to `rtype` and `p3_lkid` fields.

I hope that this answer can help you.

Comment: Thanks smukov for the detailed explanation! sure I will give a try.